# Taxi me some numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

[Taxicab Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number) or [OEIS A011541](https://oeis.org/A011541) are the least numbers that are able to be represented as \$n\$ different sums of two positive cubed integers, for successive \$n\$.

You'll need to print out the \$n\$th taxicab number. This should work for any \$n\$ in theory.

However, as only 6 taxicab numbers have been discovered so far, there won't be an \$n\$ above 6. The numbers are \$2, 1729, 87539319, 6963472309248, 48988659276962496\$ and \$24153319581254312065344\$.

You're not allowed to hard code these variables, because your program must work for any arbitrary \$n\$ in theory.

Comment: Does this require we support numbers of arbitrary length? If we can only handle values up to 2^32-1 but the program *would* work for larger values if only they were allowed, is that OK?

Comment: Sure, that's fine with me. As long as the algorithm itself would work for any number, you're good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Haskell, 60 bytes

```haskell
f n=[k|k<-[0..],n<=sum[1|x<-[1..k],y<-[1..x],x^3+y^3==k]]!!0
```

Pretty straightforward. Counts how many ways a number `k` can be written as a sum of two cubes. Filters for `k`'s such that this number is at least `n`, and takes the first one.

An equal-length method with `until`:

```haskell
f n=until(\k->n<=sum[1|x<-[1..k],y<-[1..x],x^3+y^3==k])(+1)0
```

Comment: Your program produces the smallest number that's a sum of two cubes in n different ways. The problem asks to find the n'th number which is a sum of two cubes in two different ways.

Comment: @ItaiBar-Natan It looks to me like the spec is asking for the least number that's a sum of two cubes in n different ways.

Comment: Oops, I just reread the problem and I think you're right. I guess I misread it incorrectly.

Answer (score 13):

## Taxi, 4758 bytes

What better language to calculate taxicab numbers than one that simulates taxicabs?
<sub>This is a joke. <sub>There are so many better languages. <sub>What happened to the last two days of my life?</sub></sub></sub>

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 1 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Bird's Bench.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Cyclone:w.Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Bird's Bench:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Go to Rob's Rest:n.Go to Cyclone:s 1 l 1 l 2 l.[a]Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Firemouth Grill:w 3 l 2 l 1 r.Go to The Underground:e 1 l.Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 3 l 2 l.Switch to plan "a".[b]Go to Firemouth Grill:s 1 r.[c]Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:w 1 l 1 r 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Cyclone:w.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Go to Multiplication Station:s 1 l 2 r 4 l.Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Go to Trunkers:s 1 r 2 l.Go to Firemouth Grill:e 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan "e" if no one is waiting.Switch to plan "c".[e]Go to Trunkers:w 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:w 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.[f]Go to Trunkers:s 1 l.Switch to plan "g" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Go to Cyclone:w 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Cyclone:w.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.Switch to plan "f".[g]Go to Cyclone:w 2 r.Switch to plan "h" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Firemouth Grill:w 3 l 2 l 1 r.Go to Trunkers:w 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan "g".[h]Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 r.Switch to plan "i" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Firemouth Grill:s 1 l 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Cyclone:w 1 l 1 r 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Trunkers:w 3 l.Go to Addition Alley:w 2 r 2 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 r 1 l 1 r.Go to Cyclone:w 1 l 1 r 2 l.Switch to plan "h".[i]Go to Trunkers:s 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.Go to Knots Landing:e 1 r 2 l 5 r.Go to Trunkers:w 1 l 3 r 1 l.Switch to plan "j" if no one is waiting.Go to Firemouth Grill:e 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan "e".[j]0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.[k]Go to Rob's Rest:w 1 r 2 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:s 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Rob's Rest:w 2 l 2 r 1 r.Go to Narrow Path Park:s 1 l 1 l 1 r 1 r 2 l 5 l.Switch to plan "o" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:w 1 l 1 r 2 l 1 l.Switch to plan "l" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Switch to plan "m".[l]0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.[m]Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Addition Alley:w 1 r 3 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Knots Landing:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 1 l 3 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.Switch to plan "k".[o]0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:w 1 l 1 r 2 l 1 l 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:w 1 l.Go to Addition Alley:n 4 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Bird's Bench:n 1 l 1 l 1 l 2 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 r 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Bird's Bench.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Bird's Bench:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Go to Equal's Corner:n 1 r 1 r.Switch to plan "p" if no one is waiting.Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 r.Go to Rob's Rest:w 1 r 2 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 l 1 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan "z".[p]1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Rob's Rest:w 1 r 2 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Addition Alley:s 1 l 1 l 2 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Rob's Rest:n 1 r 2 r 1 r.Go to Cyclone:s 1 l 1 l 2 l.Switch to plan "a".[z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVjLjtowFP2VKzbdRQXaDbth1JlF2yka2k2jLExiEg/GpnailPl56iQGEsd5groAhBPfx7nnHj9i9JecTs8cYg4rLmP4sd0SHy9SmAJVH5H9Oivi75IDIDggKTELsYCQExZms35GGJZog@mWyAiLo1MYM4cX8myx1drj0aecYW1E/1swPZfCrGP@kojgg4QlZn40wNFvzvf514IZrtNWK698o7y9YhkPcFaOMU9NZGnlQBcvXK3WwpElJKjjIq/N7RMReM@TOIJnQWh3GX@xAItQ8IQFjbgYNhVR5kUweWmvtS/ZWuA8t3VKYj/Knh8oYjDZTIBsgXFQeQGRkCISq2BG0UPHUPOBJo678eyRyzxi1/eGO7x2x2wQn8fS7HtCY3KgxEcx4QzWcf77n6YUgdofaj5m9P3UpRMiYTss5Jkj@m9Rhrx49jLhi26YxcUNBDLf8xUJsGe4TW@Qo7Sz7OuEsSOsdwRLWCGx0wbM4aL7HXfrWUCpszkc0TENkfRPpT@DW3M0c9mqooSeLRjzzWhE1qby3aRmdcrUC@O4kTcof3Kz@tn0jPZi9UMQkLyLHyjFx9HaZpgZ0Pz1QpRAnl@koOqgoIdeKtsje0FC8FTBr8Apkd4c1ovvtFJuGw7UQkrHJfaubQvsK@OxhG@IBVmti@mVsVzucpfwuYmBc71ZMGN6a6DUcF113DfvY8kEoDhTfOFHhAbwkuyx4JSHZ@rYHulYZx2AGBxyd15tC5ReEBmn1tUt0x12c1/@JIiqFx@5YFg0UrqSwkyvklee1chY6d8SC@qF5iO0wxp0dbBKeSvF6AjPVc5P@9DKdLtXjKT9GOnuvRZSsnHaWBOiDKO5rtIoi9Wmtx0CWppqfhEt@653p@Did2rgEhtyZb4Lx@ywMrWH7Aep1VHtWEXLp8ZOaW4@eYpe4tH75NkveJMOBozsgpNZ/EPrKtDSFTcI79A7gKvEdVku3Uk49VsK1riGvasWOHjTG1tgpFyMwrCP8EiD0eLW@5T7X26U7y5KNBati7Lt2P7unU7Tfw)
[Try it online but with comments and line breaks!](https://tio.run/##zVptj9pIEv4@v6I2X8JosjDAnpKdUVaat2RHd2GjQKTTIXbVmAY6GLfX3R7CRvntuaruBowxYGxntUgZgnE/rq566rXR7LP49q0Pbx4799D79QE6vV@hd/PfR7i7uYXOx3e3Dx9gcNaHqdahumo0eFBfiJkI@UiwuowmDfrU6CGMx4Z/BPF8yCOz4DFQoYj4CIbL9WJPjvhE@uO60syb8c/elAUTXvfkvPFn42X7Vetlo/2q@aqNAIAQN6ARFxAYHHCvFpyDUKCnHNSc@T5XevWdnjKN9wYw5DBnIw7jSM7tnfEcjExyDHohIZRKaPHEwYuHXIEIIICRGI95xAMNC7ZUdXgjI@Cf2Tz0@Qt8bPMcXkMLoT0WKw70IsAWXm3@3oYL@luHHongxJOBvyQs0BLFmXFavSRR5iKYpESoQ0daQCX9WAsZ4LOF0grGKEYTr@JqxCU58Cm1FknTfNn6efP4Fr69hp/th0sSxgL2prgujOQkYqgMlEPhZhltOow1sGAEYxGMlNEsbYBDbchG5xCqmI8kGQwffAWw3nKlLwfYRdG7vfvHzjVAowEfUcO3Iho9V3DLA296OmBvF/CDHCLeByRMHbrsCfUwXGr8SyowtPoFFYO6Yj4RAHQU8/oGcDEVPqqGrp7Dlwq2DEawN8L3UQJgUYRMqb1Bh5nLWE/hbYTfnMNC4P@JTZbjCrmgp5GMJ1PcYhagMfeCUA3nhIZ5jArkTAlyEQnoa2h4bkAt/VecZtbbUoDkUIbKHsq4pKdzDiFTiqPnokBIeFwo5kZZR7dMdK4JNE7vGgRq/BLffvyRNHpTD2M1rYlz@FpOh70oDmYoWUJ5dp/o/BgwkPiaT9KqzCPhrZMQfof2USkPSdiNg2AJ3ZlAod6zaOYk5QwNhXFBiaFvYxZKbEXfAnRUvK1dnsMPr5EZRJQvJXhohXxHfPFkKKyqDOn4Zw1PzI85MYeNRvRmxESaMhFQILNf7wDeWWWRkOfXpT2lol2nw5cT8q6wkGnA@7K7TgPe1tVUjHWtGh1@rS5ir2nT1TLiGdx1zofRiCh8opXvqrTyw8bKmBvvT7fNrlEM4H1lVr6zVr6uxiiGh1UCVkubKtDSAfZuyr1ZBgkxXClMV2JMiZD/GTNfbfLmXsAORv/L6woldKy@rzJi454sIGYqAutcXJys2i3A@7Kh5rtb@XEMC6zqZYwVG6WnEVemwXD1PyYttLl6ATJelbbDiLPZfsDfECVaCIUV/kQSWdZJr2eWzzgP8RtKczkkJIsQdbrlCsQto4QRliu1XhmbbAMajVxX58vcx8rxS2VWptL94uL6nxptKkL7Pp0UvvqVdVKmdayoiRqcvTXe9V5is/7beCw8frXA8tvHf9Td@vWz98KbxSF2EuvOwvkdLqOe9JYNuT8WCv11WXdw6etXaoV5GO9u6fky4CsY9/EqcKt9bLWPICQ1etKz/ifl3Py5CtKPXxwGSij@lAcmJTU7jGh3Vuf2jg0wyUQUqqQtHVig8u2oAyrfhxJQJe3nIGU5lSAOqrXPBgctlFLmce5/DEY8mkSU9g7wKAWLDta2ElmH2LhMAu6KWyZ00Z5oFbwh9FHNz4bPKJkFEhVO0x9YMKFRoIJu1V5pJv0Y9swQbjjIJF3hPj5nB399xNKDPYpVVqF9b1BEHZu41zoxThWPHe9iX4vQFx4zk8WuNu9/3xorbPa3znsoKP10NBE4RqzZ7D5bk1iOZduMbzJDmoR8H9fTN3qWrTyTrTkGOOlYVHag4eQoNbYhjLKTmqr2UnYe4zBKjWAcRqmpC2F8raA67HKNjuBc3BKMkaGXKzOPRaT02pApl1iUqoUWx6NTeoi5gkhft1UHuk5/TLt6J58wteMdKSqqrLUvYBS7iIH3rVRhmEyZfnfXKjufTYrks30bPEFHJ0Xww@pLb2lM0ag/cUEg5xAu4ao5JmzOGXKOz9auk2s2tnb4XHOqtWvnvvvrSa5mSMmfsIdAXaHpsJZckW03mezUf44IaQtNi5BupzgsWe9lhINd5yAmTU0qoOiSZmASx/R5lFCwkD@gmbwkFhXUmVnlmZ8v@N2MRsLUIje@z5clKrU00ClFTIZpE1Zrb2qa7YdY1rlm7oh4HaxR5AItgUpKRrL0ddcgNrc5lKUPP4vuRCNhnQ9D0gMyBRPV86zS4DmgqAFn0aYG2xfKD@3r34HUCv6DnDSksQBbF03hZwSGf@31ivaqIU5v6dM@ehYoMk3t@MmF69PG1bTo5JF0ItTnHzu7OJsxWj7QLG0H55w1U6EiyVVFVhn46TJhFIrZ2FJEHu55BJ14ziPpy8naq7O@c/ZvHeNZ2r3P@jMSxS3prbmbGKUs1rwrWoKlpgpVzIYeiFF4552MAh4dCEBbG2m59iwREnYCx1bQTbhchlPJfU5F@cf4RaqFYROsE5U2ej59d9tXt4NYttf7BwR81AjFYM5ohZKGiR36wc0R2VKRqpmLuGnB5ibC@oOVHIiZJUt@zzjrzweH3CMomkJ3UhUpvO2YURBzO65njjIP@Hh7ndf2zKJmNkJLF6GLHjW55UUPlmh5iWMkF4qLHhq55UWPiGxML3wgtPrlVsHjn5Jttz3vQK9RmirZPVGF/OxTjMFogmkoEqbCwVRdWSpKBCZb@lUT8Ezs6mTsbtvVaHdIciS6p12Fn9r@INvBA/gpr3OnhTZdxzxk2L4a0q8fsXNy4SfPZ44XhwdOeaJ8aTX/KU@2JY6fvaRsFWxUmA5PYc6k9IMZ8dvEiQFswQLze9TeiyQ5k4d4yPvdcyDTSpIcedJDmdrn5KO9TYFxFDtx2ljPOIAM9lfrf5lEG2Yl2ro5FO2ZlE@BXKFiNMgntDqqslk2ChTOuMXUnyt7q5TfReVPWL/LUecWgZvJ3vhgYZ15KNX/y@QDHs1FwDRf/37azNOal@BztTr51lNcZWUaMm@2Svb0g3h4yyI24TD49q35fw)
<sub>Note: TIO can handle an input of `1` but `2` and above cause a timeout issue. I wrote a little snippet to print the value being checked every iteration and it only got up to `137` before it timed out. If someone who knows what they're doing could run it through an interpreter (the homepage links to a [C++ version](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/taxi.cpp)) to verify higher values, I'd appreciate it. It may take a very long time to run.</sub>

Ungolfed with comments:

```
[ FIND THE NTH TAXI CAB NUMBER ]
[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number ]
[ Inspired by https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73827/38183 ]
 
[ A taxi cab number T(n) is the smallest number that can be made from the sum  ]
[ of two positive cubes in n different ways. For example, T(1) = 2 because     ]
[ 2 = 1^3 + 1^3. That is the only way to make 2 by summing positive cubes. No  ]
[ solution exists for 1 so 2 is T(1). T(2) = 1729 = 1^3 + 12^3 = 9^3 + 10^3.   ]
[ This program takes n as input and finds T(n). The (bad) psuedocode is:       ]
[                                                                              ]
[    S = STDIN;  // Use Bird's Bench                                           ]
[    T = STDIN;  // Use Rob's Rest. Saves bytes and T(n) > n is always true.   ]
[    while (true) {                                                            ]
[       // Fill an array (Firemouth Grill) with the numbers 1 through T        ]
[       // This will make it much easier to compute the cubes because a taxi   ]
[       // can only carry three passengers at a time.                          ]
[       for (i = T; i > 0; i--) { A.push(i) }                                  ]
[       // Fill an array (Trunkers) with the cubes of all integers 1 through T ]
[       for (i = T; i > 0; i--) { B.push(i ^ 3) }                              ]
[       // Fill an array (Sunny Skies Park) with each possible sum of cubes    ]
[       while (B(0) != null) {                                                 ]
[          // Make copies of the next value to add to each remaining value     ]
[          C.push(B(0));                                                       ]
[          while (B(0) != null) {                                              ]
[             C.push(C(0));                                                    ]
[             D.push(B(0));                                                    ]
[             B.shift();                                                       ]
[          }                                                                   ]
[          // Store each possible sum with this cube                           ]
[          while (C(0) != null) {                                              ]
[             E.push(C(0) + D(0));                                             ]
[             B.push(D(0));                                                    ]
[             C.shift;                                                         ]
[             D.shift;                                                         ]
[          }                                                                   ]
[       }                                                                      ]
[       // Check each possible sum to see if it equals T                       ]
[       N = 0;                                                                 ]
[       while (D(0) != null) {                                                 ]
[          if (D(0) = T) { N++ }                                               ]
[          D.shift();                                                          ]
[       }                                                                      ]
[       // If we found the desired number of sums, ouput and break             ]
[       // Otherwise, go to the next T and keep going                          ]
[       if (N = S) {                                                           ]
[          print(T);                                                           ]
[          break;                                                              ]
[       } else {                                                               ]
[          T++;                                                                ]
[       }                                                                      ]
[    }                                                                         ]
[                                                                              ]



[ S = STDIN;  // Use Bird's Bench                                         ]
[ T = STDIN;  // Use Rob's Rest. Saves bytes and T(n) > n is always true. ]
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: south 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north 1st left 1st left 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Bird's Bench.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north.
Go to Cyclone: west.
Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Bird's Bench: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
Go to Rob's Rest: north.


[ // Fill an array (Firemouth Grill) with the numbers 1 through T      ]
[ // This will make it much easier to compute the cubes because a taxi ]
[ //  can only carry three passengers at a time.                       ]
[ for (i = T; i > 0; i--) { A.push(i) }                                ]
Go to Cyclone: south 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
[a]
Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north.
Go to Firemouth Grill: west 3rd left 2nd left 1st right.
Go to The Underground: east 1st left.
Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north 3rd left 2nd left.
Switch to plan "a".


[b]
[ // Fill an array (Trunkers) with the cubes of all integers 1 through T ]
[ for (i = T; i > 0; i--) { B.push(i ^ 3); }                             ]
Go to Firemouth Grill: south 1st right.
[c]
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: west 1st left 1st right 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north.
Go to Cyclone: west.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Go to Multiplication Station: south 1st left 2nd right 4th left.
Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.
Go to Trunkers: south 1st right 2nd left.
Go to Firemouth Grill: east 1st left 1st right.
Switch to plan "e" if no one is waiting.
Switch to plan "c".


[e]
[ // Fill an array with each possible sum of cubes                ]
[ while (B(0) != null) {                                          ]
[ // Make copies of the next value to add to each remaining value ]
[ C.push(B(0));                                                   ]
[ while (B(0) != null) {                                          ]
[    C.push(C(0));                                                ]
[    D.push(B(0));                                                ]
[    B.shift();                                                   ]
[ }                                                               ]
[ Setup Cyclone with a copy of the first value ]
Go to Trunkers: west 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: west 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: north 1st right.

[f]
[ Move any remaining values to Sunny Skies Park, duplicating Cyclone each time ]
Go to Trunkers: south 1st left.
Switch to plan "g" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Go to Cyclone: west 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north.
Go to Cyclone: west.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: north 1st right.
Switch to plan "f".

[g]
[ // Store each possible sum with this cube ]
[ while (C(0) != null) {                    ]
[    E.push(C(0) + D(0));                   ]
[    B.push(D(0));                          ]
[    C.shift;                               ]
[    D.shift;                               ]
[ }                                         ]
[ Move everything at Cyclone to Firemouth Grill ]
Go to Cyclone: west 2nd right.
Switch to plan "h" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north.
Go to Firemouth Grill: west 3rd left 2nd left 1st right.
Go to Trunkers: west 1st left 1st right.
Switch to plan "g".

[h]
[ Copy Sunny Skies Park to Trunkers and add it to Firemouth Grill ]
Go to Sunny Skies Park: north 1st right.
Switch to plan "i" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Firemouth Grill: south 1st left 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Cyclone: west 1st left 1st right 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north.
Go to Trunkers: west 3rd left.
Go to Addition Alley: west 2nd right 2nd right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.
Go to Narrow Path Park: north 1st right 1st left 1st right.
Go to Cyclone: west 1st left 1st right 2nd left.
Switch to plan "h".

[i]
[ } // End of 'while (B(0) != null)' up near plan "e" ]
Go to Trunkers: south 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.
Go to Knots Landing: east 1st right 2nd left 5th right.
Go to Trunkers: west 1st left 3rd right 1st left.
Switch to plan "j" if no one is waiting.
Go to Firemouth Grill: east 1st left 1st right.
Switch to plan "e".


[j]
[ // Check each possible sum to see if it equals T ]
[ N = 0;                                           ]
[ while (D(0) != null) {                           ]
[    if (D(0) = T) { N++; }                        ]
[    D.shift();                                    ]
[ }                                                ]
[ Set N = 0 ]
0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology: west 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.

[k]
[ Pickup T ]
Go to Rob's Rest: west 1st right 2nd left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: south 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north.
Go to Rob's Rest: west 2nd left 2nd right 1st right.
Go to Narrow Path Park: south 1st left 1st left 1st right 1st right 2nd left 5th left.
Switch to plan "o" if no one is waiting.

[ Check the next value against T ]
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Equal's Corner: west 1st left 1st right 2nd left 1st left.
Switch to plan "l" if no one is waiting.

[ It's a match so N = N + 1 ]
Pickup a passenger going to Knots Landing.
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Switch to plan "m".

[l]
[ It's not a match so N = N + 0 ]
0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.

[m]
Go to Starchild Numerology: north 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley: west 1st right 3rd right 1st right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Knots Landing: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
Go to Starchild Numerology: west 1st left 3rd right 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
Switch to plan "k".


[o]
[ // If we found the desired number of sums, ouput and break ]
[ // Otherwise, go to the next T and keep going              ]
[ if (N = S) {                                               ]
[    print(T);                                               ]
[    break;                                                  ]
[ } else {                                                   ]
[    T++;                                                    ]
[ }                                                          ]
[ T is still going to Equal's Corner so just get rid of it ]
0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology: west 1st left 1st right 2nd left 1st left 3rd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Equal's Corner: west 1st left.

[ N is still going to Addition Alley so redirect it to Equal's Corner ]
Go to Addition Alley: north 4th right 1st right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.

[ Compare N = S ]
Go to Bird's Bench: north 1st left 1st left 1st left 2nd right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north 1st right 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Bird's Bench.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Bird's Bench: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
Go to Equal's Corner: north 1st right 1st right.
Switch to plan "p" if no one is waiting.

[ It's a match! The value we want is T, waiting at Rob's Rest. ]
[Go to Rob's Rest:n 3 l 1 r.]
Go to Starchild Numerology: north 1st right.
Go to Rob's Rest: west 1st right 2nd left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: south 1st left 1st left 1st right 1st right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st left 1st right.
Switch to plan "z".

[p]
[ It's not a match. T = T + 1 and start over. ]
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology: north 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Rob's Rest: west 1st right 2nd left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley: south 1st left 1st left 2nd right 1st right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north 1st left 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Rob's Rest.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Rob's Rest: north 1st right 2nd right 1st right.
Go to Cyclone: south 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
Switch to plan "a".

[z]
[ Terminate program with 10 less bytes than going back to the Taxi Garage ]
```

Comment: I love how insane of a language Taxi is.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I hadn't run into this before, but it quickly became an issue that you are able to store a maximum of 6 integer arrays and that's only because `Trunkers` and `Rounders Pub` play nicely with integers. If you're storing decimals, you only get 4 arrays. Plus, `Firemouth Grill` picks up numbers in random order so that's out if you need to maintain order. Really, you only get 2 queues and 1 stack. Good luck.

Comment: I'd complain about cheap upvotes given to submissions in funny languages, but this really deserves an upvote anyways.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
Œċ*3§ċ⁸=ð1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//xZLEiyozwqfEi@KBuD3DsDEj////Mg)

This is *ridiculously* slow, timing out for \$n > 1\$

### How it works

```
Œċ*3§ċ⁸=ð1# - Main link. Takes n on the left
        ð   - Group the previous links into a dyad f(k, n):
Œċ          -   All pairs from [1, 2, ..., k]
  *3        -   Cube each
    §       -   Sum of each
     ċ⁸     -   Count occurrences of k
       =    -   Does that equal n?
         1# - Find the first k, starting with n, which returns true under f(k, n)
              Starting with k = n is fine, as k > n for all n
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
∞εL3mãOÙN>¢}Ik>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8c1t9jHMPL/Y/PNPP7tCiWs9su///DQE)

The program timeouts for \$n>1\$ , but the algorithm works.

Answer (score 1):

### ARM Thumb-2, <s>52</s> 48 bytes for theoretical algorithm, 50 bytes for overflow safe version until n == 3

This one is hilariously inefficient, and only works for n == 3 if we assume infinite integers.

Raw machine code:

```
b570 2101 0004 000a fb02 f502 4355 0013
fb03 f603 fb06 5603 428e d101 3c01 d005
3b01 d8f5 3a01 d1ef 3101 e7eb 0008 bd70
```

Assembly:

```armasm
        .text
        .arch armv6t2
        .thumb
        .globl taxi
        .thumb_func
taxi:
        @ Nickname some registers for clarity
        n .req r0
        candidate .req r1
        i .req r2
        j .req r3
        matches_left .req r4
        i_cubed .req r5
        j_cubed_sum .req r6

        push    {r4-r6, lr}
        @ Start with a candidate of 1 (even though it's impossible)
        movs    candidate, #1
.Lcandidate_loop:
        @ reset match counter
        movs    matches_left, n
        @ start checking cubes
        @ Behold! The world's most inefficient loop!
        @ Takes 1.8 seconds for n = 2 on actual hardware. And remember, this is O(n^3). XD
        @ It also is very vulnerable to integer overflow and returns the incorrect
        @ result for n == 3. However, with sufficiently large integers, it would
        @ theoretically work fine.
        @ for (i = candidate; i != 0; --i)
        movs    i, candidate
.Li_loop:
        @ i_cubed = i * i * i
        mul     i_cubed, i, i                        @ wide insn
        muls    i_cubed, i
        @ for (j = i; --j;)
        movs    j, i
.Lj_loop:
        @ j_cubed_sum = j * j * j + i_cubed
        mul     j_cubed_sum, j, j                    @ wide insn
        mla     j_cubed_sum, j_cubed_sum, j, i_cubed @ wide insn
        @ Compare to the candidate
        cmp     j_cubed_sum, candidate
        bne     .Lno_match
.Lmatch:
        @ If it is the same, decrement matches_left
        subs    matches_left, #1
        @ Exit if we found all of the matches
        bne     .Lexit
.Lno_match:
        @ Decrement j and loop while non-zero.
        subs    j, #1
        bhi     .Lj_loop
.Lnext_i:
        @ Decrement i, and loop if it is not zero
        subs    i, #1
        bne     .Li_loop
.Lnext_candidate:
        @ Next candidate.
        adds    candidate, #1
        b       .Lcandidate_loop
.Lexit:
        movs    r0, candidate
        pop     {r4-r6, pc}
```

### Explanation

C function signature:

```c
uint32_t taxi(uint32_t n);
```

Has a wonderful O(n^3) complexity combined with billions of redundant iterations thanks to it looping backwards, but it works for n == 1 and n == 2 in reasonable time on hardware. It doesn't properly calculate n == 3 because of integer overflow.

It is a very naïve triple nested loop that is **incredibly** inefficient.

Goes through every candidate, then tests every `i` for `i <= candidate`, then tests every `j` for `j <= i`, each going backwards. It calculates cubes live, and is **horrendously** redundant and inefficient....but it is small and that is what counts.

Equivalent C:

```c
uint32_t taxi(uint32_t n)
{
    for (uint32_t candidate = 1; ; candidate++) {
        uint32_t matches_left = n;
        for (uint32_t i = candidate; i != 0; --i) {
            uint32_t i_cubed = i * i * i;
            for (uint32_t j = i; j != 0; --j) {
                uint32_t j_cubed_sum = j * j * j + i_cubed;
                if (j_cubed_sum == candidate) {
                    --matches_left;
                    if (matches_left == 0) {
                        return candidate;
                    }
               }
          }
    }
}
```

### Overflow-safe version

Here is a much faster one (but still slow) at 50 bytes which does not overflow before `n == 3`:

```
b570 2101 0004 2201 fb02 f502 4355 0013
fb03 f603 fb06 5603 428e d101 3c01 d006
3b01 d8f5 3201 428d d3ee 3101 e7ea 0008
bd70
```

```armasm
        .text
        .arch armv6t2
        .thumb
        .globl taxi_safe
        .thumb_func
taxi_safe:
        @ Nickname some registers for clarity
        n .req r0
        candidate .req r1
        i .req r2
        j .req r3
        matches_left .req r4
        i_cubed .req r5
        j_cubed_sum .req r6

        push    {r4-r6, lr}
        @ Start with a candidate of 1 (even though it's impossible)
        movs    candidate, #1
.Lcandidate_loop:
        @ reset match counter
        movs    matches_left, n
        @ start checking cubes
        @ This version loops forwards from 1 and short circuits logically.
        @ It can correctly calculate n == 3.
        @ for (i = 1; i * i * i < candidate; i++) but the check is after the loop
        movs    i, #1
.Li_loop:
        @ i_cubed = i * i * i
        mul     i_cubed, i, i                        @ wide insn
        muls    i_cubed, i
        @ for (j = i; --j;)
        movs    j, i
.Lj_loop:
        @ j_cubed_sum = j * j * j + i_cubed
        mul     j_cubed_sum, j, j                    @ wide insn
        mla     j_cubed_sum, j_cubed_sum, j, i_cubed @ wide insn
        @ Compare to the candidate
        cmp     j_cubed_sum, candidate
        bne     .Lno_match
.Lmatch:
        @ If it is the same, decrement matches_left
        subs    matches_left, #1
        @ Exit if we found all of the matches
        bne     .Lexit
.Lno_match:
        @ Decrement j and loop while non-zero.
        subs    j, #1
        bhi     .Lj_loop
.Lnext_i:
        @ Increment i, and loop if i_cubed is less than candidate.
        adds    i, #1
        cmp     i_cubed, candidate
        blo     .Li_loop
.Lnext_candidate:
        @ Next candidate.
        adds    candidate, #1
        b       .Lcandidate_loop
.Lexit:
        movs    r0, candidate
        pop     {r4-r6, pc}
```

This one is significantly faster, and does not overflow before n == 3.

Instead of looping `i` backwards from `candidate`, we loop forwards from `1`, and also short circuit when `i * i * i >= candidate`, although we do run the inner loop with this condition first so it is still very redundant.