# What's so great about 1729?

Tags: code-challenge, number-theory, optimization

*This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73827/taxi-me-some-numbers). This is asking for the nth number that can be represented as the sum of two cubes in two different ways, while that is asking for the n-th number that can be expressed as the sum of two cubes in n ways.*

### Introduction

I was just watching *The man who knew Infinity*, and I thought it would make a good challenge.

### So, what's the challenge??

You must write a program that will calculate the *n*-th number that can be expressed as the sum of two cubes, not in one way, but **exactly** two.

### Specifications

- You may output either the *n*-th number, or an array up to (and including) the *n*-th value.
- You must output both sums of cubes (however you'd like), and the number, for each output.
- You cannot hardcode any solutions.
- Runtime will be my Arch Linux laptop with 16 GB of RAM and an Intel i7 processor.
- Negitive numbers are not used.

### Winning

- The winner is the solution who's runtime for `n = 10` (in seconds) times the code size is smallest.

Comment: @orlp That is asking for the "n-th number that can be expressed as the sum of 2 cubes in *n* ways", not 2. This is different, albeit similar.

Comment: @orlp "are the least numbers that are able to be represented as **n** different sums of two positive cubed integers, for successive n." (Bold added by me)

Comment: Does it have to be _exactly_ two ways and no more, or _at least_ two ways? What about negative numbers?

Comment: Given your intro paragraph, shouldn't "but **exactly** two" be "but **exactly** n"?

Comment: Different people have different computers and runtime *will* vary. Speed can even depend on the number of background processes, making it unreliable as a metric.

Comment: You must provide timing details if you want this to be a [tag:fastest-code] competition.

Comment: 1+7+2+9=19. 19*91 = 1729!

Comment: The linked question asked for code to find the lowest (not *n*th-lowest) integer which is the sum of 2 positive cubes in *n* ways.