# Is this a Hardy-Ramanujan-Number-ish Harshad Number?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, decision-problem

### Background

The number 1729 is the Hardy-Ramanujan number. An amazing property of it was discovered by S. Ramanujan (who is widely regarded as the greatest Indian mathematician<sup>1</sup>), when G.H. Hardy paid a visit to him in a hospital. In Hardy's own words:

> I remember once going to see him when he was ill at Putney. I had ridden in taxi cab number 1729 and remarked that the number seemed to me rather a dull one, and that I hoped it was not an unfavorable omen. "No," he replied, "it is a very interesting number; it is the smallest number expressible as the sum of two cubes in two different ways."

Besides that, it has many other amazing properties. One such property is that it's a Harshad Number, i.e the sum of its digits (1+7+2+9=19) is a factor of it. That too, a special one. As Masahiko Fujiwara showed, 1729 is a positive integer which, when its digits are added together, produces a sum which, when multiplied by its reversal, yields the original number:

1+7+2+9 = 19

19 × 91 = 1729

A positive integer having such property is what I define as Hardy-Ramanujan-*ish* Harshad Number, for the purpose of this post. (There might be a technical term for it, but I couldn't find it, unless it's [member of A110921](https://oeis.org/A110921))

---

### The Task

Given a positive integer `n` as input, output a truthy or falsey value based on whether the input `n` is a Hardy-Ramanujan-*ish* Harshad Number. Output truthy, if it is. Otherwise, output falsey.

Note that only four Hardy-Ramanujan-*ish* Harshad Numbers exist (`1`,`81`,`1458` and `1729`), and you can write code which checks for equivalence with them. But I don't think that will be fun.

---

### Input

Your program should take a positive integer (a natural number, in other words). It may take it in any way except assuming it to be present in a variable. Reading from modal window, input box, command line, file etc. is allowed. Taking input as function argument is allowed as well.

---

### Output

Your program should output a truthy or falsey value. They need not be consistent. Your program may output in any way except writing the output to a variable. Writing to screen, command line, file etc. is allowed. Outputting with function `return` is allowed as well.

---

### Additional Rules

- You **must** not use a built-in to accomplish the task (I wonder any language will have such built-in, but then *Mathematica...*)
- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

---

### Test Cases

```
Input        Output
1            Truthy (because 1 × 1 (reverse of 1) = 1)
2            Falsey
3            Falsey
4            Falsey
5            Falsey
81           Truthy (because 9 (8 + 1) × 9 (reverse of 9) = 81)
1458         Truthy (because 18 (1 + 4 + 5 + 8) × 81 (reverse of 18) = 1458)
1729         Truthy (because 19 (1 + 7 + 2 + 9) × 91 (reverse of 19) = 1729)
1730         Falsey
2017         Falsey
```

---

### Winning Criterion

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Every year, on 22<sup>nd</sup> December, the birthday of Srinivasa Ramanujan, [National Mathematics Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Mathematics_Day) is observed in India. His colleagues, those in Cambridge, compared him to Jacobi, Euler, and even Newton. Besides being so great, he had almost no formal training in *Pure Mathematics*, but still, he made important contributions to *mathematical analysis*, *number theory*, *infinite series*, and *continued fractions*. Unfortunately, he died at an early age of 32 with thousands of mathematical discoveries in his mind. [A film was also made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Knew_Infinity_(film)) on him, which was based on [his biography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Knew_Infinity), *The Man Who Knew Infinity*.</sub>

Comment: "but you must not write code which checks for equivalence with them." This is a [non-observable program requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/8478).

Comment: @MartinEnder But then it will just be _does the number equal 1729, 1458, 81 or 1_. I don't think that will be any fun.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Proof: the maximum digital sum of a number with n digits is 9n. The reverse of 9n would be at most 90n. So, the product would be at most 810n^2, which must have n digits, so it must be at least 10^(n-1). When n=7, it's pretty much done, so one only has to check until 999999.

Comment: I think you should just allow checking for equivalence with them. Those sort of answers would get downvotes anyway, and will probably be longer in some cases.

Comment: @Okx Too late now, I guess

Comment: @Arjun Not really. That's why you're getting downvotes.

Comment: @Okx Done. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Was this inspired by [my Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9275/48922)?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere No, I have been knowing about Ramanujan and 1729 for last 4 years. BTW, I used to be Sting. It was I who pointed out that property of its. ;) Can't remember where, though.

Comment: @Arjun Oh, cool! It was on a deleted question of mine.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Arjun My mistake, it wasn't deleted. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80761/48922

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/wiki/Code-Page)

```
D
```

Explanation:

```
Example input: 1729
      Implicitly convert to digit list and um the digits [19]
 D     Duplicate [19, 19]
      everse [19, 91]
      muliply [1729]
      check for quality with input [1]
Implicit output: 1
```

[Try it!](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=%F0%9D%90%ACD%F0%9D%90%AB%F0%9D%95%8B%F0%9D%94%BC&input=2017)

Comment: Are the other 4 bytes unprintable? I count 1 byte

Comment: @GamrCorps It seems they are not supported by your browser. Here is an image: https://puu.sh/wpETt/9f92af18e0.png

Comment: Nice, but 5 bytes in what encoding? :-) Of the 5 characters here, [ (U+1D42C MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL S)](https://codepoints.net/U+1D42C), [ (U+1D42B MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL R)](https://codepoints.net/U+1D42B), [ (U+1D54B MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL T)](https://codepoints.net/U+1D54B) and [ (U+1D53C MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL E)](https://codepoints.net/U+1D53C) each take up 4 bytes in UTF-8 (also in UTF-16 and in (obviously) UTF-32). So this is actually 17 bytes, though I guess one could define a custom encoding optimized for ASCII + those characters.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Neim seems to use its own [code page](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/wiki/Code-Page)

Comment: @The_Lone_Devil Ah that would explain it, thanks!

Comment: @Arjun Done, don't worry about it

Answer (score 15):

## ArnoldC, 888 Bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE i
YOU SET US UP 0
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS i
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE a
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER a
HERE IS MY INVITATION 1
YOU ARE NOT YOU YOU ARE ME i
ENOUGH TALK
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE b
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER b
HERE IS MY INVITATION 81
YOU ARE NOT YOU YOU ARE ME i
ENOUGH TALK
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE c
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER c
HERE IS MY INVITATION 1458
YOU ARE NOT YOU YOU ARE ME i
ENOUGH TALK
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE d
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER d
HERE IS MY INVITATION 1729
YOU ARE NOT YOU YOU ARE ME i
ENOUGH TALK
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE res
YOU SET US UP 0
GET TO THE CHOPPER res
HERE IS MY INVITATION a
CONSIDER THAT A DIVORCE b
CONSIDER THAT A DIVORCE c
CONSIDER THAT A DIVORCE d
ENOUGH TALK
TALK TO THE HAND res
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

I know, I just check for equality, but that shouldn't be the fun part of the program.

Enjoy reading it. :)

Added some newlines there for easier readability:

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##pZLBasMwEETv/oq59dqUlqbHjb2NRCIpldYxPiZ2D4XSQvr/uCtDKAUbDLkYWTPeN4vndPn6/uy7YbByl5BMaMQ6Lgy3KE20SRwlSGTGR9GGGokFdUJ9wH2x1bPeRVBST4CjmNRWBViBD01h0ZCXLFHaZSsIm9qXBuEVbzUnscEnkK/wZzV0ZIhhp/ep4cgqOseVJeF9W0xFO01G01k6Rr3hcOCoJqPDYBNcC@uPVijjsRo/JpV8GPfB9d3lpdmHemsgtN9Nss9L2OcZ9vpGeLcE3s0t/vi0vg3fL8H3c/jnh5fb8Jf3nyUBsm06wqkotX@2UpMYEm1nZY8hlvmvzindrNL/C5wf1yQmNzzHGOOOBd8wewhHZ732uhqG9eoX)

Comment: I like you. That's why I'm going to kill you last.

Answer (score 12):

## x86 Assembly, <s>55</s> <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes:

Assumes an ABI where the return value is in EAX and parameters are pushed on the stack... so almost all of them.

```
00000000: 8B 44 24 04        mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+4]
00000004: 48                 dec         eax
00000005: 74 16              je          0000001D
00000007: 83 E8 50           sub         eax,50h
0000000A: 74 11              je          0000001D
0000000C: 2D 61 05 00 00     sub         eax,561h
00000011: 74 0A              je          0000001D
00000013: 2D 0F 01 00 00     sub         eax,10Fh
00000018: 74 03              je          0000001D
0000001A: 33 C0              xor         eax,eax
0000001C: C3                 ret
0000001D: 40                 inc         eax
0000001E: C3                 ret
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
ẹ+S↔;S×?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6OmptrTi/4/3LVTO/hR2xTr4MPT7f//jzbUMdIx1jHRMdWxMNQxNDG10DE0N7IEEsYGOkYGhuax/6MA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```hs
f n|m<-sum$read.pure<$>show n=n==m*(read.reverse.show)m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcmxDoIwEADQ3a@4oYOak9ACARPqjxiGJhyByB1NK7r47wVdfesbXXzQPKc0gHy4vcSVVSDXZ34N1KpbHJc3iBVr@Xz8RaAXhUjZd06c2E0CFvrlAD5M8gQF7DwMcNfYaNRl1aCuzbX7e4MFlljtW@Rocl13aQM)

---

**Pointfree:** (56 bytes)

```hs
(==)<*>((*)=<<read.reverse.show).sum.map(read.pure).show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcqxCoMwEADQvV9xQ4dEjmCiokLSHykOAU@UGg2X2n5@Kq6d35t9etG65jw54Zy0xUOIQjprmfyomD7EiVSa969U6Qgq@CguigeTvCAHv2zgYNxvEHnZ3nCHs8EET42dRl03HerW9MOfG6ywxubUqkRT6nbIPw)

---

**Boring:** (24 bytes)

```hs
(`elem`[1,81,1458,1729])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WIyE1JzU3IdpQx8JQx9DE1ELH0NzIMlbzf25iZp6CrUJKPpdCQVFmXomCikJuYoFCmgK6Ugx5Ix1jHRMdU6CssYGOkYGheex/AA)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```
x=>(q=eval([...x].join`+`)+'')*[...q].reverse().join``==x
```

[Try it online!](https://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=javascript-node&p=fcnRCoIwFADQd79ib7vLuDgrNOL2IyFM4i6K4XAz2d8r0ktE7PUcx5OwJBJdYSSeewc3REwdvvxzMKVRpZRqt9nYYeCZQ2RQnzVEqSjufojeMTr/AAtSS7UXU3izuvxWmzl9PLWZbepzbg/VtrZ38U/XlW6@elkB)

Basically splits into digit array, and joins with `+` and evals that expression to basically sum the digits. `string*string` will automatically convert strings into ints. Takes input as a string

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 72 bytes

This is valid ES6 submission. Add `f=` at the start and invoke like `f(arg)`.

```
n=>(y=[...`${n}`].reduce((c,p)=>+c+ +p))*[...`${y}`].reverse().join``==n
```

---

#### Test Snippet:

```js
let f =

n=>(y=[...`${n}`].reduce((c,p)=>+c+ +p))*[...`${y}`].reverse().join``==n

console.log(1 + " -> " + f(1))
console.log(81 + " -> " + f(81))
console.log(1458 + " -> " + f(1458))
console.log(1729 + " -> " + f(1729))
console.log((randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1) + " -> " + f(randomNum))
```

Comment: As I learned recently, immediately answering your own challenge is frowned upon.

Comment: @Shaggy But valid.

Comment: And I usually downvote those who do not care about the community.

Comment: @Okx, not according to the people who immediately downvoted and berated me for doing so. We need to be consistent as to whether or not this practice is allowed.

Comment: @Shaggy It's valid but frowned upon.

Comment: @LeakyNun Why is it frowned upon?

Comment: @Shaggy Why so?

Comment: @Okx Why is it frowned upon?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: I think it because it gives the challenge poster an unfair time advantage as it's possible they can make up a challenge, solve it and then post it.

Comment: [Presolving Golf Questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/presolving-golf-questions) and [Self-answering kick-starts answers, or discourages them?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/self-answering-kick-starts-answers-or-discourages-them)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
(s=Tr@IntegerDigits@#)IntegerReverse@s==#&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
SOÂ*Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2P9wk1bg//@G5kaWAA)

Comment: Bifurcate, of course. `DSODR*Q` was what I had before looking.

Comment: @carusocomputing Not sure why you'd need the first `D`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 69 Bytes

First try, with integer as input:

```
->i{(x=i.to_s.split'').inject(0){|s,a|s+a.to_i}*(x[-1]+x[0]).to_i==i}
```

Second try, with string as input:

```
->i{(x=i.split('').map &:to_i).inject(0,&:+)*(x[-1]*10+x[0])==i.to_i}
```

Comment: `.split('')` can be made `.chars`

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 164 bytes

```
@set/an=%1,s=0
:s
@set/as+=n%%10,n/=10
@if %n% gtr 0 goto s
@set/an=s,r=0
:r
@set/ar=r*10+n%%10,n/=10
@if %n% gtr 0 goto r
@set/an=%1-r*s
@if %n%==0 echo 1
```

Prints 1 on success, no output on failure.

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin, <s>111</s> 108 bytes

```
fun main(a:Array<String>)=print(a[0].sumBy{c->"$c".toInt()}.run{"${this*"$this".reversed().toInt()}"}==a[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPITcxM08j0cqxqCix0ia4pCgzL91O07YASJdoJEYbxOoVl@Y6VVYn69opqSQr6ZXkewIlNGv1ikrzqpVUqksyMou1lFRAlJJeUWpZalFxaoqGJlydUq2tLcgYzf///xuaG1kCAA)

As is typical for statically compiled JVM solutions, a lot of bytes are lost on just the main function declaration and calling print(). The meat of the function is 60ish bytes, which is not bad at all for a general purpose statically typed language like Kotlin.

## Kotlin, boring solution, 69 bytes

```
fun main(a:Array<String>)=print(a[0].toInt()in setOf(1,81,1458,1729))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPITcxM08j0cqxqCix0ia4pCgzL91O07YASJdoJEYbxOqV5HsCmZqZeQrFqSX@aRqGOhaGOoYmphY6huZGlpqa////NwIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
def f(n):x=sum(map(int,`n`));return x*int(`x`[::-1])==n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDdCoMwDIXvfYrc2YoO/4auo3sRJ1Omsl5YRSs4ZM/uSlU2FQbLzQnpl9Mk9VM8Ku6OY5YXUCCOSU/brkRlWiPGhZnwBONzk4uu4dAbsoSSPokIsZwYU8pHkbfidk/bvAUKkQYyHFOJO4k3iT/J0QSl4Qw5/jGcs8A9LZlnzxa2E2ixphVVAwwYh89vRAF1IycCfSB@9tIPEitTgRg2r@p1Ct266OvCQNwvfLUuk@tu2o2f3eoiO4vlQhsrSnde/wxeSGJ8Aw)

### Explanation

```python
def f(n):                           # define a function f that takes an argument n
    x = sum(                        # assign to x the sum of...
            map(int, `n`))          # ...the integer conversion of all elements in stringified n
    return x * int(                 # return True if x times the integer conversion of...
                   `x`[::-1])       # ...the stringified x reversed...
                              == n  # ...equals n
```

An `eval()` solution is a <s>bit</s> 2 bytes longer...

```python
def f(n):x=eval('+'.join(`n`));return x*int(`x`[::-1])==n
```

### Alternate <s>(invalid?)</s> solution, <s>42</s> 29 bytes

This solution checks for equality against all of the numbers.

```python
lambda n:n in[1,81,1458,1729]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY7dCoJAEIXvfYq5U2MN1x@0BXsRlXbLpIVcRbeLkJ7dll2jUgiamzPMnPPNdHd5aUUw1VkxXVlzrBgIIoCLHKMUIxzFKcJJsCsneR7k4cSG8wAZ5BaowkhLYCQ0EhmJEWhNZ5MmmU7hXl3ozwgfJ1ZpWXXbA1fX4X2NaEPXcyHBHklUPeytsjVMOtxFhd6asr29/T0YSfBhH26N07DOUSREOXXdRXzzM61SDl0haE6Ih8slKstWrH8er5VjegI)

Comment: Alternate alternate solution, same length: `[1,81,1458,1729].__contains__`

Answer (score 1):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 60 bytes

```
(n,g=x->x?g(x/10|0)+x%10:0)->n==g(n)*number::("%d"%g(n)).rev
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvtCoIwFEBfJQThrq626wfaYutBoh@Wmwo5ZFgMzGdf@udwOHBevW7bxoW3ng9GQgCLnfSJ8rcO/Jn4j7OTj4kLzhJlpezAsqP9jE/thIAobqN4Tyx1@hvY9U6YYY4FllgTUlHWSFV22ZBzzDhVj3RsJrCJWgYDZj@XyQ123mxdWfgD)

Answer (score 1):

## [NewStack](https://github.com/LyamBoylan/NewStack), 16 bytes

```
ḟᵢ¹f YΣ©Eᴙx| ∏=f
```

### The breakdown:

*Using 1729 as example*

```
ḟᵢ                 Define new function equal to input.               []
  ¹                Add 1 to stack.                                   [1]
   f               Multiply stack by the function.                   [1729]
     Y             Split the stack into digits.                      [1,7,2,9]
      Σ            Sum the stack.                                    [19]
       ©           Duplicate stack.                                  [19,19]
        E  |       Define new value for the first element            [19,19]
         ᴙx        Reverse first element.                            [91,19]
             ∏     Take the product.                                 [1729]
              =f   Remove from stack if not equal to the function.   [1729]
```

Prints nothing if false, and the original input if true.

Comment: _Multiply the stack by the function_. I didn't get that. Does that mean the input?

Comment: Yes and no, after `¹`, the stack consists of `[1]`. And since we defined `f` or `f(x)` to equal your input, multiplying every element in the stack by the function `f` is essentially replacing the `1` with our input. (Because `[1] * f(x)` = `[f]`)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
tV!UstVPU*=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L8kTDG0uCQsIFTL9r9LyH9DLiMuC0MuS0suQxNTCyBhbsBlaG5kCRSxtAQA)

`t` - take input and duplicate it

`V!U` - split it into individual digits

`s` - sum those digits

`t` - duplicate that sum

`VP` - turn that into a string, flip it left to right

`U` - turn that back into a number

`*` - multiply the last two values (the digit-sum and its left-to-right flipped version)

`=` - check if this is equal to the original input (which is the only other value in stack)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
¬x
*sÔ¥N
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rHgKKnPUpU4=&input=IjgxIg==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
DS×ṚḌ$$=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98l@PD0hztnPdzRo6Ji@/9w@@EJaf//G@oY6RjrmOiY6lgY6hiamFroGJobWQIJYwMdIwNDcwA)

Comment: `DS×Ṛ$Ḍ=` saves a byte.

Comment: @Dennis that is... wat witchkraft.

Comment: Just distributivity. **(1000a + 100b + 10c + d)y = 1000ay + 100by + 10cy + dy**

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 52 bytes

```php
<?=strrev($x=array_sum(str_split($argn)))*$x==$argn;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkaG5kqWTNZW8HFLYtLikqSi3TUKmwTSwqSqyMLy7N1QCKxRcX5GSWaIB1aGpqagHlbcEc6///AQ)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 36 bytes

```php
<?=in_array($argn,[1,81,1458,1729]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkaG5kqWTNZW8HFLbNzItPLCpKrNQAS@pEG@pYGOoYmpha6ICUxWpa//8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 30 bytes

```
{my \n=sum .comb;$_==n*n.flip}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

```apl
{(⍵=⍎∘⌽×⍎)⍕+/⍎¨⍕⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/FR24RqjUe9W20f9fY96pjxqGfv4elApuaj3qna@kDGoRVAFlC@9v//R71zfTKLSxTy0xTySnOTUouKFUrzUlKLFIwMDAwUMvOSc0qLM8tSFUoyEksUEouAjKLSkoxKLiegHY96N4NUcTkBzVzheGiFEwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>56</s> 52 bytes

```
n->n==(s=sumdigits(n))*fromdigits(Vecrev(digits(s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcvNCsIwEATgV1l6ysoGmv7QekgfoxfxULQpAV2XpAp9@piAXob5YEaW4PUmyYFNrCe2VkUb38@73/weFSOeXHj9Oa@3sH7UTxER0yLyOBSDnkCC5z3XqqACV94EF0PQELQEHUFPMGabrh9zDs25ZFvnRW2GK6Yv)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 5 bytes

```
Σ_x*=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///c4vgKLdv//w25jLiMuUy4TLksDLkMTUwtuAzNjSyBhLEBl5GBoTkA)

Pretty much the same as the Neim solution byte for byte.