# Is it a Harshad Number?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

A Harshad number is a number that is divisible by the sum of its digits.  This is obviously dependent on what base the integer is written in.  Base 10 Harshad numbers are sequence [A005349](https://oeis.org/A005349) in the OEIS.

### Your Task:

Write a program or function that determines whether a given integer is a Harshad number in a given base.

### Input:

A positive integer <10^9, and a base between 2 and 36, OR, a positive integer in its base, using lowercase letters for the numbers from 11-36 and a base between 2 and 36.  You only have to handle one of these options.

### Output:

A truthy/falsy value indicating whether the first input is a Harshad number in the base of the second input.

### Examples:

```
27,10 ----------> truthy
8,5 ------------> truthy
9,5 ------------> falsy
1a,12 OR 22,12 -> truthy
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins.

Comment: [closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127535/is-this-a-hardy-ramanujan-number-ish-harshad-number)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
bSḍḷ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8p@OGO3oc7tv@3Vjq8XP9R0xr3//@jjcx1FAwNYnUUoi10FExBtCWUNjQyAUrFAgA)

#### How it works

```
bSḍḷ  Main link. Arguments: n (integer), k (base)

b     Convert n to base k.
 S    Take the sum.
   ḷ  Left; yield n.
  ḍ   Test for divisibility.
```

Comment: OK, definition of FGITW right here.  Impressive though.  How do you do these things?

Comment: It's fairly easy with a base conversion built-in.

Comment: I'm just impressed by the built-in to take the sum of the digits.  Didn't even know that was a thing.

Comment: There's no built-in to take the sum of the digits. `b` converts **n** into the array of its base-**k** digits, then `S` takes its sum.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I thought b just converted n into an integer in base k.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

```python
lambda n,b:n%sum(n/b**i%b for i in range(n))<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ8kqT7W4NFcjTz9JSytTNUkhLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjT1PTxvA/SBCoFiQcrWFkrmNooKmjYaFjCiQtwaShkYmOkWasFRdnQVFmXolCmgZQueZ/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes

```python
def f(n,b):
 if b<2:return 1
 s=0;c=n
 while n:s+=n%b;n//=b
 return c%s<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCsIwEADA@75iL4UsBtqNipo2n0lNaEDWkkSkr08vCnocmHWry1OOrd1DxKhEe7KAKaKfjM2hvrIgAxY3jLMTwPeSHgHFloOTzo/S984DfuLclYnbmpNUFZW5aB6I4OurPv/o9ic2J81EbQc)

1 is truthy, you know.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcpBCoMwEEDR/ZxiNkKGBnRCizWay8QaDMhUjCCePoJFsLv/4M/7On7F5PwZAgYl2pMFjAF9Z@y8RFmRAZOr2t4J4DbGaUCx6eGk8K2UzgP@tr5IHeezVVCm1lwRweW3ft3U/InNUzNRPgA) in Python 2.

Comment: @notjagan I don't use Python 2

Comment: [-7 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcpBCoMwEEDR/ZzCjZDBgE5Q2qpzmYjigExDk2J7@giC0C7f54dvWp/qclbrWTS8k0GQpfCj6@ePJEMIkZthYoV9lW0utI8Va@kHrdnD@UxlHAlzeIkmsxh3s9QgwuW77X70@BO51hJiPvMB "Python 2 – Try It Online") in Python 2 (works in Python 3 if you redefine ∈put∈putinput to use Python 2's semantics, which is allowed, and change `/` to `//` for a 1-byte cost), using a full program with exit code returns

Comment: @musicman523.  In a different version, with 7 bytes shaved off, I would just post that myself.

Comment: @Gryphon I didn't come up with the actual code, though; I'm working on my own answer now.

Comment: Good luck beating Dennis!

Comment: @LeakyNun, base 1 is no longer required.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>54</s> 47 bytes

```python
n,k=input();m=n;s=0
exec's-=m%k;m/=k;'*n
1>>n%s
```

Time and memory complexity are **O(n)**, so don't try **10<sup>9</sup>** on TIO.

Output is via exit code, so **0** is truthy, **1** is falsy. If [this output method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/12012) winds up being allowed, a further byte can be saved by turning the program into a function.

*Thanks to @musicman523 for suggesting exit codes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P08n2zYzr6C0REPTOtc2z7rY1oArtSI1Wb1Y1zZXNds6V98221pdK4/L0M4uT7X4/38jcx0FQwMA)

Comment: Can you change the language to "Python 2 interpreter" and use `exit(n%s)` where 0 is truthy and anything else is falsy?

Comment: Found something even shorter, thanks to your suggestion. :)

Comment: Nice! I thought maybe you could incur a ZeroDivisionError, but your way is shorter I believe

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <strike>12</strike> 7 bytes

```
!%hQsjF
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21%25hQsjF&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B27%2C+10%5D%0A%5B8%2C+5%5D%0A%5B9%2C+5%5D%0A%5B23%2C+12%5D&debug=0)

Byte count is now lower since unary is no longer required.

#### Explanation

```
!%hQsjF
     jF    Fold the input over base conversion (converts given number to given base)
    s      Sum the values
  %hQ       Take the first input modulo that sum
!          Logical not, turning 0s from the modulus into True and all else into False
```

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 20 bytes

```
{⍺=1:0⋄⍵|⍨+/⍺⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOpHvbtsDa0MHnW3POrdWvOod4W2PlDoUdfSR72LD603fNS1CChe@///o44ZemlA6Ue9mw1N/wMA) <sub>[15 first numbers in 15 first bases]</sub>

Takes the number as a right argument and the base as a left argument, 0 is truthy.

**How?**

`⍺⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵` - `⍵` in base `⍺` as a list of digits

`⍵|⍨` - `⍵` modulo ...

`+/` - the sum

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
¦ΣB²¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm18enHpiffGh5YeWPGpqLHrUNuFR26TyQ9v@H1p2brHToU2Hdv7//9/QQMHInMtUwQKILbkMjRSMjAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>64</s> 60 bytes

(requires the `pryr` package)

```r
pryr::f({d=pryr::f('if'(n<b,n,n%%b+d(b,n%/%b)));!n%%d(b,n)})
```

This is an anonymous function that takes two arguments, `b` and `n` that evaluates to (which is on TIO):

```r
function(b,n){
   d=function(b,n)
     if(n<b) n else n%%b + d(b,n%/%b)
   !n%%d(b,n)
}
```

where `d` computes the digit sum for the required base.

Dropped 4 bytes once the base was guaranteed to be greater than 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jSSdPs5pLIcUWRYRLQSEzTSPPJklTIU8hNac4VSFPVTVJQVshBSStqq@aBFSiCBRLgSiv/Z@mYWigY2Su@R8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
vUsV ¬xnV
```

Takes input as two integers.

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=dlVzViCseG5W&input=MjIgMTI=)

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```
n=>k=>!(n%eval([...n.toString(k)].map(_=>parseInt(_,k)).join('+')))
```

Note that since we are required only to handle either base-*k* or base-10 numbers for `n`, I assume `n` is a base-10 integer always.

-1 byte, thanks to TheLethalCoder!

How it works:

```
!                                    # Convert to true if 0 else false
 (n%                                 # Compute n modulo
    eval(                            # evaluate string
         [...n.toString(k)]          # convert to array of base-k divisors
         .map(_=>parseInt(_,k))      # map lowercase characters to ints
         .join('+')                  # join array as string of characters
    )                                # get the raw remainder, and let ! do its work
 )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcuxDoIwEADQ3a/AwXAX4aJNDDrA7uxoDClYSKFem7bh9ytxlPUlb5KLDL3XLpad7JQp2b5VGuoEXMxYN3vgg1qkgScRMUX7iF7zCDO@6CMdtHXjpA/qzhHadSBNVjPkxxwRU285WKPI2BEGEFWRnU@Iuz8WK4sN34rsssHrD9MX)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Take input in currying syntax to save a byte i.e. `n=>k=>...`, would be called like `(345)(10)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 54 bytes

```java
n->b->{int s=0,c=n;for(;c>0;c/=b)s+=c%b;return n%s<1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBRS8MwFIXf9ysOhUKLXe0qgq5rBZ8U0QnzrfQhTbOZ2aUlSYcy@ttn2nVzauAm4eS7OYe7Jlsyrmom1sXHvm7yklPQkiiFZ8IFdiNgUJUm2hzbihfYmDdnoSUXqzQDkSvl9iiwNv/5jealv2wE1bwS/j1/lazglGg2exSarZj0hjNBjXjvCC93x8mOCw0VBx6NRbSspBPRJIjoZZy76iKmdh5JphspIGw1m0TtPuodTVeamRSaKa0QDzm6tUMYeJh01XpnKm484PqfentQg19qGBouPGfbg20XsLfujacHe/fknldVyYiAZKoptYlV@x3hdFsaZF7Pp5PMjf40sM@aUc0K09IjYYYEwZFafCnNNn7VaL8209dLx7KvCjMD5EQx2KG5K1uB4IFI9U4KiGaTMwnHVq4trMH3LIB3jHgHy5rCwsv8zTqJcfwTyADzJwuGMQjMdcjejrpq998)

Comment: Shown as curried, TIO as non-curried.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
{~(+/y\x)!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrpOQ1u/MqZCU7Gi9n@agp66hpG5gqGBtYWCqbUlEBsZKRgaaf4HAA)

A function taking an integer (`x`) and the base to use (`y`).

- `y\x` convert `x` to a base-`y` representation
- `+/` take the sum of the digits
- `~(...)!x` check if the sum of the digits mod the input integer is non-zero

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6, 62 bytes

```
n=>b=>!(n%[...n.toString(b)].reduce((x,y)=>x+parseInt(x,b),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 37 bytes

```c
f(n,b,i,s){n?f(n/b,b,i,s+n%b):i%s<1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYrBCsIwEETv@xWhEkhw1SYgtrboj3gxia0Luoqpp9Jvj0Gv0jk8mHnjV733KXWK0SFh1CMfc9m4X12ydHpPMrammRIsiP3tHS6ijUOgx/p6ACAexP1MrDSMIHKerzx1qpDhxAWKTtkdmhIzS62b/5cKt1jN@Dr7esZbi8Zi5vcyQfoA)

Returns zero for true, non-zero for false.
I want to know, why not just `i%s` does work, but `i%s<1` does (*isn't that very strange?*).

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 40 bytes

```perl6
{$^b>1??$^a%%[+] $a.polymod($b xx*)!!?1}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##TY5bboMwEEX/ZxUTyalMMVBHSfpACVlE/9qmMuC0SAZb2FSglBV1F90YhaRS8jlX99wzRtZqPTRW4tc6zGIoO7zJdC5xMxzJPt3yJCF7MZ@/@G9IRGi06kqdU5Ji2956s1nC@2Fkdk5ahxtURSUt9cJSmKcjIPq/P2Gmy5RGr7kfeQyTyNWN@@wihuQdepjMzyMbg1GiQv80FMNB1/@bwRbprqhM4xiRrZGZkzkjH4V1Hk6GwuL0L/0@l0bFpYanHvTD4p7xOwyCceyshwe2mu6r5PGSHISyHfDFkvFr6A8)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with placeholder parameters ｢$a｣ and ｢$b｣

    $^b > 1          # declare ｢$b｣ and compare against 1

  ??                 # if ｢$b > 1｣ then:

      $^a            # declare ｢$a｣
    %%               # is it divisible by
      [+]            # reduce the following with &infix:<+> (sum)
        $a.polymod(
          $b xx *    # infinite list of ｢$b｣s
        )

  !!                 # if ｢$b <= 1｣ then:

    ? 1              # Boolify 1 (shorter than True)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
#2<2||Tr@IntegerDigits@##∣#&
```

Pure function taking two arguments, the integer and the base (in that order), and returning `True` or `False`. Careful: the first two `|`s are just the normal ASCII character, while the last `∣` is U+2223.

`#2<2` deals with the special case of base 1. Otherwise, `Tr@IntegerDigits@##` produces the sum of the digits of the first argument when written in the base of the second argument, and `...∣#` tests whether that sum divides the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 119 bytes

```
@if %2==1 echo 1&exit/b
@set/at=%1,s=0
:l
@if %t% gtr 0 set/as+=t%%%2,t/=%2&goto l
@set/at=%1%%s
@if %t%==0 echo 1
```

Outputs 1 for Harshad numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda n,b:int(n,b)%sum(int(i,b)for i in n)<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ8kqM69EA0hrqhaX5mqAOJlATlp@kUKmQmaeQp6mjeH/giKQeJqGkpG5ko6CoYGmJhdcyNAYKGSKImKCIZIE0makqfkfAA)

Based on the updated formats for input.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 57 bytes

```c
f(n,b,t,s){while(b>1&&t){s+=t%b;t/=b;}return b<2||n%s<1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc3dCoIwGMbxc6/iRVA2muSkqHhdV9KJW36BvYRbeKDeemvUuXT4/PnBY7LWGP@oemJ8jqAnByQ0RkCqOCFoJXN8jiE3LE7uN4pFwwIQJHLOv@yMENgRYZtd/mOyOGA43WSr/00nLJ@nrh9qpq8yTR2f7U65RKPbK43rWLvXSKDLYlkosaXE1fu3aYaqtT6bPg)

Comment: Is passing extra parameters allowed? Or is it the only way here..

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 25 bytes

```
(n,b)->n%sumdigits(n,b)<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYhZCoAgEECvMgiBwggpRAXVRcIPKwrBZGiBOr1Zfb2F7ObkQnGGFiIPOAjZhWw/18kt7ti/06hoifzNL5Ad0ObCkZS9wWC03vMZ4RICoe91iSo3ySosXtQ/tEaljRHxAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-!`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
%ìV x
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=JexWIHg&input=MjIKMTI)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>49</s> 43 bytes

```c
a,b;f(x,n){for(a=x,b=0;b+=x%n,x/=n;);a%=b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dclNCsIwEEDh/ZwiVAIJHbUKUmWMJ3GTH6MBnUqtECg9eyy41bd8n19evS/FoqOoMrIeY9crazI605CrTZaMeW2YNFlpHE0FFon9/R0u4vgaQupWtxNA4kE8bGKlYQQx9@znFVUlw5krFFFtW9w0WtNv3ePurx2@NkH5AA)

Returns zero for true, non-zero for false.

It is very simple. It just accumulates all the digits of `x` in `b` and returns `x % b`.

Ungolfed version:

```c
// local variables
int a, b;
int f(int x, int n)
{
    // Accumulate all digits in b
    // Note that the for loop only checks x /= n
    for (a = x, b = 0; b += x % n, x /= n;)
        ;
    // Then return a % b.
    return a % b;
}
```

Thanks to dingledooper for the -6 bytes!

Comment: You may use the return hack to achieve [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##dclNCsIwEEDh/ZwiVAIJHbUKUmWMJ3GTH6MBnUqtECg9eyy41bd8n19evS/FoqOoMrIeY9crazI605CrTZaMeW2YNFlpHE0FFon9/R0u4vgaQupWtxNA4kE8bGKlYQQx9@znFVUlw5krFFFtW9w0WtNv3ePurx2@NkH5AA).

Comment: Thanks! [undefined behavior ｉｎｔｅｎｓｉｆｉｅｓ]

Answer (score 0):

## x86 Machine Code, 19 bytes

```
50 31 C9 99 F7 F6 01 D1 85 C0 75 F7 58 99 F7 F1 85 D2 C3
```

The above bytes define a function that accepts the value in the `EAX` register and the base in the `ESI` register, and sets the zero flag (`ZF`) based on whether the value is a Harshad number (`ZF` will be clear if the value is a Harshad number).

Note that this is a custom calling convention, defined expressly for the purposes of this challenge. Assembly/machine language programmers are allowed to do that. However, note further that the choice of the `ESI` register for the second parameter (base) is completely arbitrary. This can be changed to any other unused general-purpose integer register (*i.e.*, `EBX`, `EDI`, or `EBP`) without affecting either correctness or code size.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZNbS8MwFMff@ykOkUI7qtOKeJ1XJu7Fl70MGZQsiVukTWsuMif76tZk7URn50Dz0vb8z@9cek7I9piQskyu8zyFnrrDUk0wvTfZiMnACMXHglF4walhEXx@j7BioffmgT0VKpkyqT6tLAlWWZIEaCiGujBqkgL4PsNTtJCXZyFPc2lVJ5NpVD1@eF0RYjKTYs38zklDDEKfG6yUv9SRFW@QMaW1TNcmHmrNlF5WH61t4knM3PvXOhu8iryoMzYG2dTFhvrqLuh3rxNAnUtCZgiCakIhQLsFubFz0fXQgAt4uHXerfYKixFAsBh@WNksy4VDCyxxxjSTju5eDVbYCFDfsW5R4He23/uZ1zX7tVfHkjQf2aVU0L0Z2MrHXLkIK2xYbaBk2kjxuZTzcosLkhrK4EzZX5rvTM49jwsNGeYiWG5yIa3pMUC@GgoUQbB6HeLDCPZ2Q7gAJHLk6nxlCoV1zk00HEUAB3@mj/9Dx7GtPG6i5175Th5TPFbldrYffwA)**

In ungolfed assembly language mnemonics:

````
; bool IsHarshadNumber(unsigned value, unsigned base)
;
; Inputs:
;    EAX = input value
;    ESI = base
; Outputs:
;    ZF = 0 if Harshad number; otherwise, ZF = 1
; Clobbers:
;    EAX, EDX, ECX
;
        IsHarshadNumber:
50         push   eax             ; preserve input value
31 C9      xor    ecx, ecx        ; zero-out accumulator

        Accumulate:               ; <----------------------------------------------------\
99         cdq                    ; zero-out EDX (based on EAX) to prepare for division  |
F7 F6      div    esi             ; divide by base (EAX = quotient; EDX = remainder)     |
01 D1      add    ecx, edx        ; accumulate remainder                                 |
85 C0      test   eax, eax        ; is quotient 0?                                       |
75 F7      jnz    Accumulate      ; keep looping until it is ----------------------------/

58         pop    eax             ; restore input value
99         cdq                    ; zero-out EDX (based on EAX) to prepare for division
F7 F1      div    ecx             ; divide by accumulator
85 D2      test   edx, edx        ; set ZF based on remainder
C3         ret
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```ruby
->n,b,s=0,i=n{(s+=n%b;n/=b)while n>0;i%s<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ0mn2NZAJ9M2r1qjWNs2TzXJOk/fNkmzPCMzJ1Uhz87AOlO12Maw9n@BQlq0kbmOoUEsF4hpoWMKYVjCGEZGOoZGsf8B)

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```ruby
f=->n,b,s=0,i=n{n>0?f[n/b,b,s+n%b,i]:i%s<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5PJ0mn2NZAJ9M2rzrPzsA@LTpPPwkkpp2nmqSTGWuVqVpsY1j7v0AhLdrIXMfQIJYLxLTQMYUwLGEMIyMdQ6PY/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,b,s=0,i=n)=>n?f(n/b|0,b,s+n%b,i):i%s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcjdCkAwFADge@@hdnKwreSnxrMYpklnMrny7pNL8V1@S3/2ftjtdqTkxikEoxihRq84WkWgWuoMo1xf/NmEYo0WGhv7MDjybp2y1c3MMFmi4ADReyssPlf/nJQoJEC4AQ)

Returns zero for true, non-zero for false.